# Why does $u \perp \text{ker}(A-I)$ imply that $u$ eigenvector of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say $A \in \text{SO}(3)\setminus \{I\}$ and $\text{dim }(\text{ker}(A-I)) =2$. Let $ u \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $u \perp \text{ker}(A-I)$.

Why does this imply that $u$ must be an eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: $SO(3)$ are rotations and $ker(A-I)$  is spanned by  the 1 eigenvector, the rotation axis. u is in the rotation plane, and corresponds to an imaginary eigenvalue, so its an eigenvector in the complex space, not the real space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the kernel of $A - I$, and let $L$ be its orthogonal complement. We're assuming $P$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which means $L$ is a line.

Since $A$ is an orthogonal map, it preserves orthogonality. In particular, $AL$ is orthogonal to $AP$. The plane $P$ is an eigenspace of $A$, so $AP = P$. That means $AL$ is orthogonal to $P$. Equivalently, $AL$ is contained in the orthogonal complement of $P$: in other words, $AL \subset L$.

Finally, pick a vector $u \in L$. From the previous paragraph, we know that $Au \in L$. I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is normal, and you know $1$ has algebraic multiplicity $\ge 2$, so the characteristic polynomial splits over $\mathbb R$, so there must be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$. Knowing $\ker(A-I)$ is 2-dimensional doesn't leave much choice for the last eigenvector.

Comment: I know, but how do you know for certain that $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: You know an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors exists, and you know two of them must come from $\ker(A-I)$. Where must the third come from? It's in a (complex) 1-dimensional orthogonal space, so that must be the correaponsding eigenspace.

Comment: That's extremely helpfull!

Comment: You don't actually need to pass to the complex numbers to prove this; you just need that the characteristic polynomial splits. I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. A rotation cannot have eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity 2. Purely logically, anything can be concluded from a false hypothesis. Unless you agree to call the null vector orthogonal to everything?

Comment: I know, but this is part of a proof of the statement you just made (which I'm trying to understand), in which they are trying to get to a contradiction by assuming that the kernel has dimension two.

Comment: So, do you, apart from the fact that it leads to a contradiction, see why this implication has to be true?

Comment: How much are we allowed to assume? If the eigenvalue 1 has multiplicity 2 and the determinant is 1, can we conclude that we are missing a real root in the characteristic (cubic) equation?

Comment: That part of the proof I get, but my question cencerns the part before that. From the fact that $u$ is an eigenvector, they conclude it has to be an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1, and come to a the contradiction that $A=I$ (which they assume is not the case because it's a rotation). The only thing I don't get is why $u$ has to be an eigenvector if it's perpendicular to $\text{ker}(A-I)$?